# Cordova issue when getting from git plugin wakeuptimer

Tags: android, git, cordova

I am doing `cordova plugin add https://github.com/wnyc/cordova-plugin-wakeuptimer.git` but it doesn't work

> Error: Failed to fetch plugin
>   https://github.com/wnyc/cordova-plugin-wakeuptimer .git via git.
>   Either there is a connection problems, or plugin spec is incorrect:
>           Cannot find plugin.xml for plugin '1460155233779'. Please try adding it again.

here my cordova project in this zip http://www12.zippyshare.com/v/ANROAer1/file.html

Comment: I just installed the plugin using [Git](cordova plugin add https://github.com/wnyc/cordova-plugin-wakeuptimer.git) but its not getting added in the index.html of my app.